# Compile time error and Constructor "Super"

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

just a quick question that I hope somebody could give an explanation for.

What happens when a class's constructor does not explicitly invoke the constructor of its superclass using "super." Similarly, what cases would lead to compile - time erorr? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when a class's constructor does not explicitly invoke the constructor of its `superclass` using "`super`."

constrcutor in subclass will have `default call` to `no arg default constrcutor` of `super` class.

and hence it calls `super class no arg default constructor.`

if `super` class does not have `no arg default constructor` then it will definitely throw compile time error.

lets see scenario

```
class A{

}

class B extends A{

}
```

this internally becomes

```
class A{
A(){
}

}

class B extends A{
B(){
super();
}
}
```

This will work definitely with no errors as default constructor present in class A.

now if A does not have default constructor (happens when we write our own constructor)

```
class A{
A(int a){

}

}

class B extends A{

}
```

this will be internally have

```
class A{
A(int a){

}

}

class B extends A{
B(){
super();//compile time error as no default constructor in class A
}
}
```

Solution

1)define either default constrcutor explicitely in class A

or

2)call parameterized constrcutor of A from B like `int x =0; super(x);` explicitely

Answer (score 3):

it implicitly invokes default constructor of super class if present, results in compiler error otherwise